# Mint 19 - rkhunter 1.4.6 won't update

Tags: rkhunter

System: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 64-bit, based on Ubuntu 18.04.

RKHunter: packaged version 1.4.6-2.

Unfortunately, when I try to update its database, I get error:

---

```
$ sudo rkhunter --update

[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.6 ]

Checking rkhunter data files...
  Checking file mirrors.dat                                  [ Skipped ]
  Checking file programs_bad.dat                             [ Update failed ]
  Checking file backdoorports.dat                            [ Update failed ]
  Checking file suspscan.dat                                 [ Update failed ]
  Checking file i18n versions                                [ Update failed ]

Please check the log file (/var/log/rkhunter.log)
```

---

I checked the log with no real result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this by editing the following file:

```
/etc/rkhunter.conf
```

And changing a few values as follows:

```
# If this option is set to '1', it specifies that when the '--update' option is used, then the mirrors file is to be checked for updates as well.
UPDATE_MIRRORS=1

# 0 - use any mirror
MIRRORS_MODE=0
```